# Is there any easy way to use Pandas to read data from clipboard while data have string columns with varying white space?

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following data

```
                StadiumType                   Turf  Temperature  Humidity      GameId
0                   Outdoor             Field Turf         63.0      77.0  2017090700
1                  Outdoors           A-Turf Titan         65.0      53.0  2017091000
2             Green Outdoor                  Grass         64.0      57.0  2017091001
3               Red Outdoor  UBU Sports Speed S5-M         68.0      43.0  2017091002
4                   Outdoor                  Grass         63.0      53.0  2017091003
```

I found that using `pd.read_clipboard()` doesn't work well because the white space.  I ended up with awkward `split` and `join` using `with` context manager.  Is there any easier way than this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: [`pd.read_clipboard("\s\s+")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples#comment94739875_20159305) works for this data.

Comment: Oh gosh, works like charm!  Thanks a million!

Comment: @MustafaAydın What!?  This is like magic.  I've needed this for years!  (Though wouldn't your code be much more readable with single quotes?)    :-)

Comment: @jch Glad it's useful! (but I kindly disagree with the last part of your comment :p)